# C# Raw Sockets Port Forwarding

Tags: c#, networking, sockets, portforwarding

I am trying to create a simple C# app which does port forwarding, and need to know how to use the IP_HDRINCL socket option to try to fake out the receiving end to think the connection is really to the source. Any examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sock = new Socket( AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP );
sock.Bind( new IPEndPoint( IPAddress.Parse( "10.25.2.148" ), 0 ) );
sock.SetSocketOption( SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, 1 );   
byte[] trueBytes = new byte[] { 1, 0, 0, 0 };
byte[] outBytes = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
sock.IOControl( IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, trueBytes, outBytes );
sock.BeginReceive( data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback( OnReceive ), null );
```

The only problem is that I've been able to successfully receive data from a raw socket like this, (including the IP header) but not send it.

Answer (score 3):

Newer versions of windows restrict the use of raw sockets due to malware heavily abusing them.

Quoted from the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740548%28VS.85%29.aspx)

> On Windows 7, 
>   Windows Vista, and Windows XP with
>   Service Pack 2 (SP2), the ability to
>   send traffic over raw sockets has been
>   restricted in several ways:
>
> - TCP data cannot be sent over raw sockets.
> - UDP datagrams with an invalid source address cannot be sent over raw sockets. The IP source address for any outgoing UDP datagram must exist on a network interface or the datagram is dropped. This change was made to limit the ability of malicious code to create distributed denial-of-service attacks and limits the ability to send spoofed packets (TCP/IP packets with a forged source IP address).
> - A call to the bind function with a raw socket for the IPPROTO_TCP protocol is not allowed. 
>     **Note**  The bind function with a raw socket is allowed for other protocols (IPPROTO_IP, IPPROTO_UDP, or IPPROTO_SCTP, for example.
>
> These above restrictions do not apply to Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008 , Windows Server 2003, or to versions of the operating system earlier than Windows XP with SP2.

Answer (score 0):

> IP_HDRINCL

.NET's Socket type does support RAW, and there is `SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded` for use with `Socket.SetSocketOption`.

You may want to use Reflector to double check the .NET implementation aligns with the enum values.

Answer (score 0):

I found this website, but not sure how well the code works: http://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/clientserversocketnetworkcommunication8h.html

Comment: Let me save you some time.  The code mentioned here has mal-referenced methods and does not compile.  Don't wast your time here :)