# is it possible to forge a packet in .net?

Tags: .net, udp, packet

I think my question is "no comment", and I must say is is not a bot-net.it is for education.

please tell me if this kind of question (hacking related) is not allowed in stackoverflow.

Edit:

```
While(Countries::C_Iran::LastMessage::Nuclear>0.05)IAEA::GetCountryA(Countries::C_Iran::Handle)->Boycott++;
if(IAEA::GetCountryA(Countries::C_Iran::Handle)->Boycot!=0)Sourceforge::GetCountryPermissions(Countries::C_Iran::Handle)->DnyAnything();
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to forge?

Comment: You do realise that forging the IP means (most likely) that you won't receive the reply...

Comment: I am trying to do a scatter shot in my network.(B Requests A for data)->(A sends message to B and C(this one is forged))->(B sends data and C starts Listening)->(C tells A that process is finished)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, if you need to send forged or custom-made packets, it's always a good idea to see if there is a port of libpcap for your platform. In this case, there are at least two:

http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/sharppcap/index.php?title=Main_Page

EDIT: here's a tutorial for sharpcap http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sharppcap.aspx#sendPackets

Comment: @Chinmay Kanchi:sharppcap didn't help.because While(Countries::C_Iran::LastMessage::Nuclear>0.05)IAEA::GetCountryA(Countries::C_Iran::Handle)->Boycott++;

Comment: Can you post this as an edit please? I can't really understand the code as it is.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you'd use raw sockets to do that - there's a bit of info in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567954/c-raw-sockets-port-forwarding) that should get you started.

Comment: +1,I think the link helps a lot,but I'm going to wait a few hours for an example or something.