# Port Forwarding with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, portforwarding

I am trying to write a program that launches a game server, the only problem is that I do not know how to port forward with vb.net or if it is even possible? It is for a game

Comment: i think it probably depends on how you are defining "port forwarding".  here is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567954/c-raw-sockets-port-forwarding. if you could describe exactly what you need (e.g. if you don't really need full port forwarding) then there's more chance we could help :) thanks!

Comment: @shelly I need to be able to port forward for hosting a server for a game

Comment: i saw that much :) but, can you please describe the problem more fully?  do you need full port forwarding as described in the linked post (which looks like is not really possible with later versions of windows)? or do you just need to be able to take data on one port and send it out another? do you need to spoof IPs? is it for a game you are writing or one that already exists? etc. the question is so open-ended that i have no idea where to start...

Comment: @Shelly, Sorry... Umm it is a game called minecraft and normal you would have to just go into your router setting and add a port to forward. I don't have much experience in it sorry, I am only just starting programming

Comment: There's no such thing as "ports" in VB.NET. You need to do this at the level of your firewall. Are you using the built-in Windows Firewall? Do you have Administrative privileges?

Comment: @Cody Sorry, I guess I am a bit out of my level... All I know is that I want to do the same as you would with your router settings... I just want to know if it is possible to do something like that to make it easier for my friends to port forward for a game

Comment: Uh, so you're using an external router? Like one that's plugged into the network *separately* from your computer? Then the problem is that you'll have to find a way to communicate with your router. And that's going to be pretty difficult to do unless the router is specifically designed for that. All of the consumer routers that I've seen are not really meant to be configured from anything but a web browser using their own interface.

Comment: @Cody, ok I don't think this is going to be possible at my level of programming, thanks for everyones help

Comment: It's not really about your level of programming... This task is complicated by a host of external factors like your ability to write software on a client machine that communicates with the router. If there's no API for the router, you're probably out of luck. This is, of course, a security feature. Otherwise, what would stop malware that got loaded on your computer from reconfiguring your router, or entire network, to let itself do as it wished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the [UPnP APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382303.aspx).

Otherwise you might try the [dotnetportmapper library](http://code.google.com/p/dotnetportmapper/).